# How to remove duplicate imagemagick icons

Tags: launcher, imagemagick

I see two imagemagick icons.

[image: The imagemagick have two icons]

Can I remove them (or just one of them)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is normal, both desktop files are installed with it:

```
$ dpkg -S desktop | grep imagemagick
imagemagick: /usr/share/applications/display-im6.desktop
imagemagick-6.q16: /usr/share/applications/display-im6.q16.desktop
```

Two options here:

- If you do not need ImageMagick you may remove its packages with
   `sudo apt-get purge imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16`
  (but it may remove essential packages from system such as CUPS)
- Try to hide icons with `alacarte` (*easy GNOME menu editing tool*).

Comment: By the way, Removing imagemagick is VERY dangerous, because it can break `cups`.